# Как для трех баз данных изменить свойство колонки и потом проверить все свойства этой колонки?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, oracle

Как для postgres, mssql, и для oracle изменить свойство null нa not null колонки и потом проверить Все свойства этой колонки во ВСЕХ базах? Один запрос на изменение. И один для проверки на тип и длину, и is nullable.

Comment: Что значит "проверить", если вы попытаетесь сделать колонку not null, а в ней на этот момент будут null, то запрос просто не пройдет

Comment: В смысле? Да в прямом! Надо взять колонку и узнать какие у нее сейчас заданы свойства. Конечно запрос не пройдет, и?

Comment: ...и всё. Свойства колонки оракла можно посмотреть в системном вью `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`. У остальных СУБД - ищите в их документации. Унифицированного способа нет. Для изменения, формально, можно написать более-менее стандартный DDL запрос, но я не дам гарантию, что он сработает везде одинаково.

Comment: И что такое "Все" свойства колонки, речь вроде шла о not null, какие еще свойства интересуют

Comment: @mike вы не знаете какие есть свойства у колонок?

Comment: @Dmitry ну поэтому я и прошу чтобы мне подсказали, так как я не знаю как это все сделать. Ну и я же все таки не просил посоветовать мне почитать доку, мне бы уже готовый пример, так как времени мало.

Comment: @alexsafsafsd Я примерно подозреваю какие свойства есть у колонок. но у всех перечисленных СУБД есть дополнительные, уникальные свойства, которые присущи только тем СУБД и которые могут отсутствовать в унифицированных средствах получения такой информации, так как они не стандартны. Поэтому я и спрашиваю какие именно свойства интересуют. Кроме того вы пишите слово "потом", которое подразумевает некие связанные действия. Типа сначала сделали not null, а потом проверили что длина не менее 100 символов. но в СУБД может не быть нормальных средств объединить эти действия в одно

Comment: @mike мне не нужно делать это все в одном запросе. Один запрос на изменение. И один для проверки на тип и длину, и is nullable.

Comment: @mike ок, сорри. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Ну теперь вообще волшебно стало. Типы (точнее, названия типов) уж точно у всех разные.

Comment: @ Dmitri, и? Я же поэтому и прошу что бы мне мне помогли с каждой базой!

Comment: Я думал, вам надо одно более-менее унифицированное решение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Изменение свойства колонки `X` на not null:

```
Oracle:      alter table test modify X not null;
Ms sql:      alter table test alter column X VARCHAR not null;
Postgresql:  alter table test alter column X set not null;
```

Как видно из примера, в случае использования MS SQL непосредственно установить атрибут NOT NULL, не указывая при этом тип данных колонки, невозможно.

Информацию о типах данных, длине, признаке NOT NULL на колонках можно получить следующим образом:

```
Oracle:     select * from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
             where owner='владелец' AND table_name='таблица' and column_name='колонка'

Ms sql и
Postgresql: select * from information_schema.columns
             where table_schema='схема' AND table_name = 'таблица' AND column_name = 'колонка';
```